# Move the NaNs from the end to the beginning of each column while maintaining the order of the numbers in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I don't know how to move the nan present in each column to the beginning of each of it, translating the different values from nan to the bottom of the column.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np 

    q = pd.Series(dtype=int)
    w = pd.Series(data=np.array([6,23,4]))
    e = pd.Series(data=np.array([2,3,7,89,12,45]))
    r = pd.Series(data=np.array([98,25,84,12]))
    t = pd.Series(data=np.array([36,41,74,29,86,77,55]))
    
    q = pd.concat([q, w], axis=1)
    q = pd.concat([q, e], axis=1)
    q = pd.concat([q, r], axis=1)
    q = pd.concat([q, t], axis=1)
    
    print(q)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution (maybe not the best):

I would use shift function and apply it for each column.

But first we need to name cols properly as later indexing and shifting of values will be done by column names.

```
col_names = ["A","B","C","D","E"]

q.columns =col_names # renaming cols by list

cols_nan = q.isna().sum() # counting NaN values per each col and placing into pd.series / dataframe

df = q.apply(lambda x: x.shift(periods = cols_nan[x.name])) #using lambda to shift each columns by values in the cols_nan
```

out:

```
   A     B     C     D   E
0 NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  36
1 NaN   NaN   2.0   NaN  41
2 NaN   NaN   3.0   NaN  74
3 NaN   NaN   7.0  98.0  29
4 NaN   6.0  89.0  25.0  86
5 NaN  23.0  12.0  84.0  77
6 NaN   4.0  45.0  12.0  55
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this make sense to you?

```
columns = [
    [6, 23, 4],
    [2, 3, 7, 89, 12, 45],
    [98, 25, 84, 12],
    [36, 41, 74, 29, 86, 77, 55]
]

max_length = max(len(column) for column in columns)
data = [
    [None for _ in range(max_length - len(column))] + column
    for column in columns
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype=int).T
print(df)
```

Result:

```
      w     e     r   t
0   NaN   NaN   NaN  36
1   NaN   2.0   NaN  41
2   NaN   3.0   NaN  74
3   NaN   7.0  98.0  29
4   6.0  89.0  25.0  86
5  23.0  12.0  84.0  77
6   4.0  45.0  12.0  55
```

Comment: Yes, I'd like to get this.

Comment: But the dataframe is created inside a loop, so for me it is not possible to use the "pd.DataFrame" function. At each iteration I add a column that can be shorter or longer than the previous one and it automatically add NaN to the end of each column.

Comment: I see. What about filling a list within the for loop and using it later (when all columns are added) to create the df? (I updated the proposed solution)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with `key` parameter:

```
df = pd.concat([q, w,e,r,t], axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(key=pd.notna).to_numpy())

print(df)
    0     1     2     3   4
0 NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  36
1 NaN   NaN   2.0   NaN  41
2 NaN   NaN   3.0   NaN  74
3 NaN   NaN   7.0  98.0  29
4 NaN   6.0  89.0  25.0  86
5 NaN  23.0  12.0  84.0  77
6 NaN   4.0  45.0  12.0  55
```

Another idea is swap order of arrays and after `concat` use [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
q = pd.Series(dtype=int)
w = pd.Series(data=np.array([6,23,4])[::-1])
e = pd.Series(data=np.array([2,3,7,89,12,45])[::-1])
r = pd.Series(data=np.array([98,25,84,12])[::-1])
t = pd.Series(data=np.array([36,41,74,29,86,77,55])[::-1])


df = pd.concat([q, w,e,r,t], axis=1).sort_index(ascending=False, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
    0     1     2     3   4
0 NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  36
1 NaN   NaN   2.0   NaN  41
2 NaN   NaN   3.0   NaN  74
3 NaN   NaN   7.0  98.0  29
4 NaN   6.0  89.0  25.0  86
5 NaN  23.0  12.0  84.0  77
6 NaN   4.0  45.0  12.0  55
```